# How to handle private configuration file when deploying?

Tags: django, github

I am deploying a Django application using the following steps:

Push updates to GIT
Log into AWS
Pull updates from GIT

The issue I am having is my settings production.py file. I have it in my .gitignore so it does not get uploaded to GITHUB due to security. This, of course, means it is not available when I PULL updates onto my server.

What is a good approach for making this file available to my app when it is on the server without having to upload it to GITHUB where it is exposed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is definitely a good idea not to check secrets into your repository.  However, there's nothing wrong with checking in configuration that is not secret if it's an intrinsic part of your application.

In large scale deployments, typically one sets configuration using a tool for that purpose like Puppet, so that all the pieces that need to be aware of a particular application's configuration can be generated from one source.  Similarly, secrets are usually handled using a secret store like Vault and injected into the environment when the process starts.

If you're just running a single server, it's probably just fine to adjust your configuration or application to read secrets from the environment (or possibly a separate file) and set those values on the server.  You can then include other configuration settings (secrets excluded) as a file in the repository.  If, in the future, you need more flexibility, you can pick up other tools in the future.